# CURL connection to domain name pointed at itself gives "Connection Refused"

Tags: centos, curl

I have a PHP website on CENTOS which needs to get the contents of its own homepage in order to cache it. To do this I need to use the full URL of it's own domain name that resolves to itself.

I tried doing a Curl -I website.com but the connection comes back as "Connection Refused". It works on any external domain but itself.

I believe there must be a firewall rule that's causing it to block connections from itself but there are none set, and I even tried disabling the firewall completely. There is already a loopback adapter from ifconfig.

Comment: maybe the webserver is listening only on external interface. Check with "netstat  -pntl" if the IP is 0.0.0.0 (or :: for IPv6) or the external one

Comment: is it behind nat,  did you setup hairpinning

Comment: @Dom All are either 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.7.

Comment: @JacobEvans It's hosted on an Azure VM, there's no NAT.

Comment: What webserver are you using (configuration?) ? Can you show the iptables -L -v -n (or active firewall) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using `nano` to edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add the domain name of the website to the servers external IP

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your DNS is messed, you need to check what IP resolves to your domain.

try running `dig yourdomain.com A` on the machine your are testing. If the response doesn't include your IP address, then maybe the problem is in your DNS.

Comment: It returned the 127.0.0.1 IP address which I thought was correct. I had to make entries for it to point to the external IP address which worked. I'm not sure why the first option didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your site really listens on 80/tcp port and there is no iptables-related problems, you can try localhost, like this `curl -I -H "Host: website.com" localhost`. Also, it is possible that your site listens only on https-port (443/tcp), so it can respond to `curl -I https://website.com`